# How to call the filename of running SQL script?

Tags: oracle, plsql

I'm trying to run a series of script files but I would like for each script file to print its filename, for reporting.

So, the intent is to call each SQL file from a general script:

```
@SQL_File_1;
@SQL_File_2;
@SQL_File_n;
```

But I need each SQL to print it's results, so I need each to print:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE({Filename} || ' updated ' || {Number of records});
```

How to retrieve the filename? Can it be easily done?

Comment: Easily? No, as far as I can tell. See this OraFAQ Forum discussion: http://www.orafaq.com/forum/t/62944/0/

Comment: According to that, the information is stored in a package using Module parameter. He just used a function to convert it & get the filename only. But I get “SQL*Plus” or “Toad (version)” instead; not sure why I don't get the current file directory.

Comment: From my point of view, the simplest way is to hard-code script name into the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are running SQL*Plus, then it can be done as per the comment but only if you've set APPINFO, eg

```
SQL> select module from v$session where sid = sys_context('USERENV','SID');

MODULE
----------------------------------------------------------------
SQL*Plus

SQL> host cat x:\temp\myfile.sql
select module from v$session where sid = sys_context('USERENV','SID');
SQL> @x:\temp\myfile.sql

MODULE
----------------------------------------------------------------
SQL*Plus

SQL> SET APPINFO ON
SQL> @x:\temp\myfile.sql

MODULE
----------------------------------------------------------------
01@ x:\temp\myfile.sql
```

That will also work with SQLcl.

I haven't used TOAD for a while but I think it also supports appinfo

Comment: Thanks! It seems I can work with this, at least using SQLPlus. In Toad it never changed "Toad (version)", but it's better anyway.

Comment: Just a heads up, this worked. & with the correct formatting this is gold. Thanks!

Comment: On my VirtualBox VM instance running Oracle Database 19.3, there's no `@` symbol after the nesting level in the output. I wonder whether that's purely a software version issue, or if there's something else more interesting going on.

Comment: And the answer is: SQL*Plus sets module using the format `%02d@ %s`, whereas SQLcl uses the format `%02d %s` (no `@` symbol).

Answer (score 0):

The  [utility](https://github.com/dmitrydemin1973/powershell-oracle/blob/master/run_all_sql_dir.ps1) executes all sql files in the specified directory and complements the calls to sql files with prompt commands to display the sql file name.

For example input file

```
C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql   
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
31.12.2020  11:42                28 SQL_FILE1.sql
31.12.2020  11:42                28 SQL_FILE2.sql
31.12.2020  11:43                28 SQL_FILE3.sql
31.12.2020  11:43                28 SQL_FILE4.sql
31.12.2020  11:43                28 SQL_FILE5.sql
```

For example output log

```
SET session NLS_LANG: AMERICAN_AMERICA.CL8MSWIN1251
===========================================================================================
Script start time :  2020-12-31 11:50:11 
Found SQL file  C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE1.sql  
Found SQL file  C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE2.sql  
Found SQL file  C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE3.sql  
Found SQL file  C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE4.sql  
Found SQL file  C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE5.sql  
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

For example output sqlplus short log, if `set termout OFF`

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Thu Dec 31 11:48:58 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> 
Session altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> 
Session altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> SQL> SQL> Start script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE1.sql
SQL> SQL> Stop script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE1.sql
SQL> SQL> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL> Start script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE2.sql
SQL> SQL> Stop script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE2.sql
SQL> SQL> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL> Start script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE3.sql
SQL> SQL> Stop script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE3.sql
SQL> SQL> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL> Start script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE4.sql
SQL> SQL> Stop script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE4.sql
SQL> SQL> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL> Start script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE5.sql
SQL> SQL> Stop script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE5.sql
SQL> SQL> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL> SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

For example sqlplus output full log, if `set termout ON`

```
SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.4.0 Production on Thu Dec 31 11:50:12 2020

Copyright (c) 1982, 2013, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> SQL> 
Session altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> 
Session altered.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> SQL> SQL> Start script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE1.sql
SQL> SQL> select 1, sysdate from dual;

     1 SYSDATE
---------- -------------------
     1 31.12.2020 11:50:09

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> Stop script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE1.sql
SQL> SQL> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL> Start script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE2.sql
SQL> SQL> select 2, sysdate from dual;

     2 SYSDATE
---------- -------------------
     2 31.12.2020 11:50:09

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> Stop script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE2.sql
SQL> SQL> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL> Start script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE3.sql
SQL> SQL> select 3, sysdate from dual;

     3 SYSDATE
---------- -------------------
     3 31.12.2020 11:50:09

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> Stop script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE3.sql
SQL> SQL> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL> Start script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE4.sql
SQL> SQL> select 4, sysdate from dual;

     4 SYSDATE
---------- -------------------
     4 31.12.2020 11:50:09

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> Stop script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE4.sql
SQL> SQL> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL> Start script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE5.sql
SQL> SQL> select 5, sysdate from dual;

     5 SYSDATE
---------- -------------------
     5 31.12.2020 11:50:09

1 row selected.

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
SQL> Stop script: @C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\SQL_FILE5.sql
SQL> SQL> > --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SQL> SQL> Disconnected from Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't think in a controlled environment in wihch, for example, a DBA Team this would work though. Usually instructions for groups like that are "run SQL", so if I came with different code, I would probably get into troubles making it work.

Answer (score 0):

This powershell script adds  `sqlplus` command `PROMPT` sql file names to sql file before call sql script.

```
 <# .SYNOPSIS
     This script adds PROMPT sql file names to sql file before call sql script.
     Author: Dmitry Demin dmitrydemin1973@gmail.com

    .DESCRIPTION
     This script adds PROMPT sql file names to sql file before call sql script.
    
    .PARAMETER sql_file_input

     Specify the input sql script.

    .PARAMETER sql_file_output

     Specify the output sql script.

    .PARAMETER log_file

     Specify the log file.

    .EXAMPLE
     This script adds PROMPT sql file names to sql file before call sql script.
    .\add_prompt_file_names.ps1  -sql_file_input .\sql\start.sql -sql_file_output .\sql\start_prompt.sql -log_file log_file.log
#>


param(
[string]$sql_file_input="C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\start.sql",
[string]$sql_file_output="C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git\sql\start_prompt.sql",
[string]$log_file="log_add_prompt.log"
)

$upper_line = "PROMPT ""Start script: "
$bottom_line = "PROMPT ""---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"""

                       


$date_time_start = Get-Date -Format "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"            

Write-host "Script start time : $date_time_start "
try
{
echo "Script start time :  $date_time_start ">>$log_file
}
catch {
Write-Host "Log File $log_file.  Other type of error was found:"
Write-Host "Exception type is $($_.Exception.GetType().Name)"
exit
}

echo "===========================================================================================" | tee-object -Append  -filepath $log_file
echo "Input sql file: $sql_file_input"  | tee-object -Append  -filepath $log_file
echo "Output sql file: $sql_file_output"  | tee-object -Append  -filepath $log_file

$data_file = Get-Content $sql_file_input

$null | Set-Content -Path $sql_file_output

foreach ($line_file in $data_file)
{

  if ($line_file.TrimStart().StartsWith("@"))

  {

   $start_prompt_line= $upper_line + $line_file.TrimStart().replace("@","")  + """"
   
   Out-File -filepath $sql_file_output -append  -inputobject $start_prompt_line -encoding default
   Out-File -filepath $sql_file_output -append  -inputobject $line_file.TrimStart() -encoding default
   Out-File -filepath $sql_file_output -append  -inputobject $bottom_line -encoding default
  }

  else 
  {
   Out-File -filepath $sql_file_output -append -inputobject $line_file -encoding default
  }
    
}
```

For example

```
C:\upwork\powershell-oracle_git>powershell .\add_prompt_file_names.ps1  -sql_file_input ./sql/start.sql -sql_file_output ./sql/start_output.sql  
    
Script start time : 2021-01-03 16:32:41
============================================================================
Input sql file: ./sql/start.sql
Output sql file: ./sql/start_output.sql
```

Input file ./sql/start.sql

```
REM
REM
REM 
---
rem start 1
@SQL_FILE1.sql
rem start 2
@SQL_FILE2.sql
rem start 3
@SQL_FILE3.sql
rem start 4
@SQL_FILE4.sql
rem start 5
@SQL_FILE5.sql
REM
REM
---
```

Output sql file: ./sql/start_output.sql

```
REM
REM
REM 
---
rem start 1
PROMPT "Start script: SQL_FILE1.sql"
@SQL_FILE1.sql
PROMPT "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
rem start 2
PROMPT "Start script: SQL_FILE2.sql"
@SQL_FILE2.sql
PROMPT "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
rem start 3
PROMPT "Start script: SQL_FILE3.sql"
@SQL_FILE3.sql
PROMPT "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
rem start 4
PROMPT "Start script: SQL_FILE4.sql"
@SQL_FILE4.sql
PROMPT "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
rem start 5
PROMPT "Start script: SQL_FILE5.sql"
@SQL_FILE5.sql
PROMPT "---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
REM
REM
---
```